# Why is there 2 separate, different endpoint in OAuth2? (/authorization and /token)

Tags: oauth2

I know they both serve different purpose, but that does not answer why the need for 2 separate endpoint when it could have been done using just 1 endpoint? We pass different parameters when we request for authorization and access token, so using one endpoint should work, no?

I feel like I'm missing some historical context/reasoning (or I'm just super dumb), but I couldn't find any.

Comment: What single endpoint do you believe should it be? Would it make sense to have e.g. the /authorization endpoint serve access tokens?

Comment: You could conceivably lock down the token endpoint to known sources - while the authorisation endpoint needs to be open to all….

Comment: @Spyros the authorization endpoint can and does issue access and identity tokens, via the hybrid, auth code and implicit flows (not all those flows issue all tokens all the time tho).

Comment: @Moo indeed, but my question aimed at making the OP think whether a single endpoint could be used to provide both functionalities. Maybe I should have asked whether it would make sense to have the /token endpoint grant authorizations

Comment: @Spyros Didn't implicit flow use one single endpoint? Which endpoint we ends up using does not matter, but they certainly can be done using a single endpoint, no? Right now it makes no sense because of the naming, but assuming we have the right endpoint naming, I think it could make sense

Comment: Farid-EN anything is possible technically. However when you design protocols and APIs you should aim for simplicity and extensibility. Having a single endpoint serve all flows has some benefits (e.g. you have one endpoint to work with as a client) but also complicates and constrains things (e.g. you need to differentiate the interaction with the endpoint based on parameters). Also, it does not allow for the flexibility to isolate different parts of the API either access- or implementation-wise (as @Moo pointed out)

Comment: @Farid-EN to expand on my earlier comment, I have an OAuth2 complaint identity provider which is locked down to use the auth code flow only for interactive logins, and the token endpoint is a second server hidden behind a VPN - I know exactly who will be using the token endpoint, so I can ensure that that endpoint is very very secure.  Any endpoint open to the public however is open to attack - if I remove the option of issuing tokens via that public endpoint, I reduce the attack surface considerably.  This also plays into the concept of removing tokens from untrusted clients.